# Opening phone's camera capture from browser automatically saves image locally

Tags: javascript, android, html, image-uploading, image-capture

I am opening the camera of a phone so the user can select and image and upload it to the server.

Seems like that on `android 4.4.2` and also 'android 4.1.2' when the user clicks on the image capture button - the image capture dialog is open.

The user than takes the picture, but if he clicks cancel (or ok) it creates a local copy of the image on the phone.

i have checked it on android version > 5 and it didn't seem to happen there

** Added example code **

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Try Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Press:
<input type="file" id="input">
</body>
</html>
```

**question**

Is there a way to tell the phone not to save the image locally? (i just want it to upload to my server without filling the phone's memory with a lot of images).

Comment: how are you invoking camera, can you please share your code ?

Comment: Here is an example, it happens in this code as well:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;  initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=0;" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Try Page</title>

</head>
<body>
Press:
    <input type="file" id="input">
</body>
</html>

Comment: I guess I am wrong person to answer this, I thought you were invoking camera using media store intent. Sorry !.